# How to split test a menu item

Tags: plugins, testing

I have four links in my main navigation menu, which is displayed on every page of my site.

`Link 1 | Link 2 | Link 3 | Link 4`

I have a form that once completed is a goal/conversion and redirects to a success page.

I'd like to split test a different menu where one of the links goes to a different page.

Variant A: `Link 1 | Link 2 | Link 3A | Link 4`

Variant B: `Link 1 | Link 2 | Link 3B | Link 4`

How can I test which link (3A or 3B) leads to more form completions?